# testing try-catch in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am having issues when trying to test the catch statement within a saga. I am using Mocha and chai, which is failing the below test with `Error: error` outputted to the console.

saga.js

```
function* submitCredentials(action) {
  try {

  } catch(e) {
    yield put({type: LOGIN_FAIL, message: e.message})
  }
}
```

test.js

```
it('should catch errors', () => {
  const generator = submitCredentials();
  const error = new Error('error');

  expect(generator.throw(error).value, put({
    type: actions.LOGIN_FAIL, error
  }));
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the expect line need to be `expect(generator.throw(error).value).to.equal(put({
    type: actions.LOGIN_FAIL, 'error'
  }));`

Comment: Or rather...`expect(generator.throw(error).value).to.equal(put({
    type: actions.LOGIN_FAIL, {message: 'error'}
  }));`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
 const generator = submitCredentials();
 const error = new Error('error');
 generator.next().value
 output = generator.throw(error).value
 let expected =  put({
    type: actions.LOGIN_FAIL, error
 })
 expect(output).toEqual(expected)
```

Comment: That gives the same outcome as my example

Answer (score 0):

Your generator dispatches an action with the error message, but in your test you're expecting the action payload to be the error object. So if you change it to expect

```
put({
  type: actions.LOGIN_FAIL, {message: 'error'}
})
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

before you let the generator produce the error , it has to be a step where can the generator execute the next step : generator.next().value